# How to save multiple images to targeted folder in Opencv Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm working in a project for Image Processing, I have already created the code for cropping and resizing it, however I didn't know how to save the multiple images into targeted folder.

Here is my code

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import numpy
import cv2

filepath = 'DataMentah/akMundur'
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(filepath) if isfile(join(filepath))]
images = numpy.empty(len(onlyfiles), dtype = object)
for n in range(0, len(onlyfiles)):
    images[n] = cv2.imread(join(filepath, onlyfiles[n]))
    crp_img = images[0:240, 0:80]
    h = 224
    w = 224
    dimension = (h, w)
    rsz_image = cv2.resize(crp_img, dimension, interpolation = CV2.INTER_AREA)
    #saveimage to targeted folder
```

Comment: Use cv2.imwrite() in you for loop saving rsz_image. `cv2.imwrite("result_{0}.png".format(n), rsz_image)`

Comment: @fmw42 how to add the path for targeted save folder?

Comment: does `crp_img = images[0:240, 0:80]` work for you? this seems odd. `images` is a `len(onlyfiles)` sized array of images, each images is a x*y*3 or 4 numpy array of pixels. What do you think `crp_img = images[0:240, 0:80]` is`? it is not reffering to one image ...

Comment: @PatrickArtner i think thats my logical error, i try to crop and resize all the image in folder at once. i knew that the read file code is working but not with the crop and resize code for multiple image, so what should i fix here?

Comment: Post the error message for starters ... nand try something like `crp_img = images[n][0:240, 0:80]` or `crp_img = images[n,0:240, 0:80]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply write the images and make the number of your loop part of the name:

```
for n in range(0, len(onlyfiles)):
    # other things you need to do snipped
    cv2.imwrite(f'/path/to/destination/image_{n}.png',image)
```

that way you get ordered names for it. You can use mini format language to format `n` like so:

```
for n in range(5):
    print(f"filename_{n:04}.png")   # format as 4 digits with leading zeros
```

Output:

```
filename_0000.png
filename_0001.png
filename_0002.png
filename_0003.png
filename_0004.png
```

See [string format mini language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) for more formatting options.